# Recognizing special cases of a defined function for permuted arguments

Tags: function-construction, pattern-matching

I have a number of ugly ways to implement the following **pattern recognition** task, but I'm looking for something elegant to keep my notebook tidy.

I need to define a function of six variables $f(a,b,c;A,B,C)$ which is known to be unchanged under the simultaneous interchange of any two of $a,b,c$ and of the corresponding $A,B,C$:

$$\begin{align}&f(a,b,c;A,B,C) = f(a,c,b;A,C,B) = f(b,a,c;B,A,C) \\
 =&f(b,c,a;B,C,A) = f(c,a,b;C,A,B) = f(c,b,a;C,B,A)\end{align}$$

**EDIT for clarity: Given one definition, how do I get** ***Mathematica*** **to try all possibilities within the** ***restricted*** **set of permutations shown above for pattern matching?  I need to mimic the effect of** `SetAttributes[f,Orderless]`.

More concretely, if I define the special case:

```
f[a_, 0, b_, A_, 0, C_] := (a+b)/(A-C)
```

a function call `f[x, y, 0, m, n, 0]` should match, and return `(x+y)/(m-n)`.  But `f[x, y, 0, m, 0, n]` should *not* match, and thus return it must be returned unevaluated.

**Added question:**  Instead of finding a way to get *Mathematica* to try all the possibilities when pattern matching, would it be easier to write code such that when a representative definition for `f` is made, the kernel automatically adds further definitions of `f` for the remaining permutations of the arguments?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think Bob Hanlon had the right idea in using [`Orderless`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Orderless.html) but his suggestion is overly naive.
Instead we must treat only the triplets as orderless so we will need an additional head.

***Edit:*** my answer was also wrong, but I am updating it with the correction from your comment below.

```
SetAttributes[f1, Orderless]

f[a_, b_, c_, A_, B_, C_] := 
 With[{body = f1[{a, A}, {b, B}, {c, C}]}, body /; Head[body] =!= f1]

f1[{a_, A_}, {0, 0}, {c_, C_}] := (a + c)/(A - C)
```

Now:

```
f[x, y, 0, m, n, 0]

f[x, y, 0, m, 0, n]
```

> ```
> (x + y)/(m - n)
>
> f[x, y, 0, m, 0, n]
> ```

Comment: This is better, but the invariance of the function $f$ isn't for permutations of first three arguments $a,b,c$ independent of the second three $x,y,z$.  They are tied together.  But no problem; your answer and @BobHanlon's answer pointed me in the right direction:  I could declare `SetAttributes[f1, Orderless]` but with the arguments arranged `f1[{a_,x_},{b_,y_},{c_,z_}]`, and make the library of special cases for `f1`.  Then finally, I put `f[a_,b_,c_,d_,e_,f_] = f1[{a,x},{b,y},{c,z}]`.  I tried a few cases and it seems to work.  What do you think?

Comment: Sorry, you're right, I wasn't thinking clearly.  Hopefully thinking better now, and your solution sounds just fine.  Why don't you self-answer so I can vote for it?

Comment: @QuantumDot This question just got bumped by Community♦ because it has no positively voted answer.  Please post the method in your comment above as a self-answer.  If you don't I shall edit my answer to include it.

Comment: Thanks for the notification; you can go ahead and include the solution your answer.  Then I'll mark it as accepted.

Comment: It appears that I have certain cases where an explicit form is not known and thus no pattern matches.  In that case, the function call to `f[a,b,c,x,y,z]` would return `f1[{a,x},{b,y},{c,z}]`.  I'd like it to return `f` instead of `f1` which is supposed to be an internal function.  Do you know how this can be accomplished without resulting in an infinite loop?

Comment: @Quantum I keep forgetting about this.  Once again I don't have (or want to take) time for this right now.  (It's Labor Day here and fine weather too.)  What you want should certainly be possible.

Comment: Might this be a good way to enable definitions through `f` instead of `f1`?: `f /: SetDelayed[f[a_, b_, c_, d_, e_, f_],  expr_] := (f1[{a, d}, {b, e}, {c, f}] := expr)`.  Ditto for set.  Sometimes I overlook pitfalls with such workarounds.

Comment: @MichaelE2 thanks for the response, I'm not entirely sure how this works and how to use it.  Exactly where do I insert this line?  Maybe you can explain in an answer?

Comment: @QuantumDot Example: `f[a_, 0, c_, d_, 0, f_] := (a + c)/(d - f)` should define value for `f1`, so that if any corresponding pair are both zero, then the value is given by the formula.  The code overrides `:=`, so that a value for `f1` is set instead of one for `f`.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Your corrected answer is working very nicely.  I will wait for further answers/comments.

Answer (score 16):

I think you need to use a group-theoretical construction. In this way you will have full freedom in specifying any group of permutations you need. In your case the group is

```
G = PermutationGroup[{Cycles[{{1, 2}, {4, 5}}], Cycles[{{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}}]}];
```

This generates a symmetric group on {1, 2, 3}, which also forces the same permutations on {4, 5, 6}. These are the group elements, as permutation lists:

```
PermutationList[#, 6] & /@ GroupElements[G]
```

> ```
> {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}, {1, 3, 2, 4, 6, 5}, {2, 1, 3, 5, 4, 6}, {2, 3, 1, 5, 6, 4}, {3, 1, 2, 6, 4, 5}, {3, 2, 1, 6, 5, 4}}
> ```

There are six permutations, corresponding to those of the symmetric group on {1, 2, 3}.

Now construct the following function:

```
SetAttributes[SetDelayedPermuted, {HoldAll, SequenceHold}];

SetDelayedPermuted[f_[args___], rhs_, group_] := ((f[##] := rhs) & @@@ Permute[{args}, group];)
```

Let us try your definition, though I'm changing the - sign in the denominator to a + sign, because otherwise I think there is some inconsistency:

```
SetDelayedPermuted[f[a_, 0, b_, A_, 0, C_], (a + b)/(A + C), G]
```

Now we check your two cases (remember I changed a sign):

```
f[x, y, 0, m, n, 0]
```

> ```
> (x + y) / (m + n)
> ```

```
f[x, y, 0, m, 0, n]
```

> ```
> f[x, y, 0, m, 0, n]
> ```

We can see how many definitions were actually needed:

```
??f
```

> ```
> Global`f
>
> f[b_,0,a_,C_,0,A_]:=(a+b)/(A+C)
> f[b_,a_,0,C_,A_,0]:=(a+b)/(A+C)
> f[0,b_,a_,0,C_,A_]:=(a+b)/(A+C)
> ```

Note how symmetry in both a<->b and A<->C was implemented simultaneously (hence we ended up with 3 definitions, instead of 6). That's why I think a consistent definition was having (a+b)/(A+C) or (a-b)/(A-C) but not (a+b)/(A-C) on the right hand side.

Comment: Nice answer! and kudos to you for making the RHS consistent.  I like especially how it generates the necessary definitions.

Comment: A really nice solution! Congratulations, bounty hunter. :-)

Comment: I edited your code to make it a bit shorter.  I also changed the formatting with hope of making it easier to copy and paste the code sections.  I hope you don't mind.

Comment: Thank you QuantumDot! And thank you Mr.Wizard for improving the answer.

Comment: Thanks for this! I actually have an application where a function I'm interested in is only partly symmetric. I think I'll use this instead of what I have now.

Answer (score 5):

I would do this by defining a preferred ordering to sort the first three arguments. 
In this example I will use canonical Mathematica `Ordering` but in principle you could use anything.

I would define

```
f[a_, b_, c_, A_, B_, C_] := With[
   {order = Ordering[{a, b, c}]}, (* Get ordering of first three arguments *)
   f @@ {
     Sequence @@ ({a, b, c}[[order]]), (* Sort first three arguments *)
     Sequence @@ ({A, B, C}[[order]])  (* Reorder second three similarly *)
     }
   ] /; Not[OrderedQ[{a, b, c}]] (* Avoid infinite loop. *)
```

Then

```
f[c, b, a, C, B, A]
(* = f[a, b, c, A, B, C] *)
f[3, 0, -3, foo, bar, baz]
(* = f[-3, 0, 3, baz, bar, foo] *)
```

etc.

Comment: How I'd have done it: `f[a_, b_, c_, A_, B_, C_] /; ! OrderedQ[{a, b, c}] :=  f @@ Flatten[{{a, b, c}, {A, B, C}}[[All, Ordering[{a, b, c}]]]]`

Answer (score 1):

Give f the attribute `Orderless`

```
SetAttributes[f, Orderless];

f[0, 0, 0, 0, z_, z_] = -(1/z);
f[0, 0, 0, 0, y_, z_] = -(1/(y - z)) Log[y/z];

f @@@ Permutations[{0, 0, 0, 0, z, z}] // Union
```

> {-(1/z)}

```
f @@@ Permutations[{0, 0, 0, 0, y, z}] // Union
```

> {-(Log[y/z]/(y - z))}

Comment: This won't work because $f$ isn't completely orderless among all six variables.