# Output function control and manipulation for efficient computation

Tags: list-manipulation, pattern-matching

I have taken note of a similar post related to modifying [function parameters](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/73869/how-to-modify-the-output-result-of-an-evaluation). I tried to adapt Kuba's solution to this post but I can't get it to work. I will illustrate my problem using a similar notation used in the other post.

I have a function, $f$, that has an *arbitrary*, but even number of arguments; i.e.  $f(A,B,C,D,E,F)$. The parameters $A,B,C,D,E,F$ actually represent variables which I integrate over. Now two different variables may be switched, but the evaluation of the integration of such a function will not change since all we have done is switch the 'dummy' variable.

So I have a function that generates a lot of these such functions and I want Mathematica to use this to simplify the output. For example, if I have as the output of my function:

```
expr1 = f[2, 2, 1, 3, 3, 1] + f[2, 2, 3, 1, 1, 3] + 
         f[3, 3, 1, 2, 2, 1] + f[1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 2];
```

I want mathematica to generate the output:

> 4f(1,1,2,3,3,2)

Since the integration of all of these functions will be the same. Of course, more than 1 switch of variables can be made. The number of arguments can increase to an arbitrary even number. Additionally, any pair of arguments can be switched **EXCEPT** the last pair. i.e.

```
expr2 = f[1, 3, 2, 2, 3, 1] + f[2, 2, 1, 3, 3, 1] + f[2, 2, 3, 1, 1, 3]
```

should give:

> 2f(2,2,1,3,3,1) + f(2,2,3,1,1,3)

Since the first two functions are the same but the third is not - since the last pair in the third function has been switched by the second pair (compared to the second pair). So any pair can be switched **BUT** not the last pair of arguments.

Writing a function that acknowledges that these functions are the same enables a reduced number of integration evaluation - important when each integration takes long to evaluate.

Thanks very much for your help.

Comment: `SetAttributes[f, Orderless];f[2, 2, 1, 3, 3, 1] + f[2, 2, 3, 1, 1, 3] + f[3, 3, 1, 2, 2, 1] +  f[1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 2]` solves the first part

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Read the [faq]!
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge.
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: At the end I don't know if my answer was of any help so I removed it.

Comment: Your first example and the additional requirement for your second example are inconsistent.  Please clarify.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way.

For example you can define :

```
f1[x__, p1_, p2_] := f2[x][p1, p2]
SetAttributes[f2, Orderless];

f3[x__][p1_, p2_] := f[x, p1, p2]
```

**Test**

Your **initial output**  can be generated this way :

```
myargs = {{2, 2, 1, 3, 3, 1}, {1, 3, 2, 2, 3, 1}, {2, 2, 3, 1, 1, 3}};
mysum = Plus @@ f @@@ myargs
```

> f[1, 3, 2, 2, 3, 1] + f[2, 2, 1, 3, 3, 1] + f[2, 2, 3, 1, 1, 3]

Then

```
mysum /. f -> f1
```

> f2[1, 2, 2, 3][1, 3] + 2 f2[1, 2, 2, 3][3, 1]

```
mysum /. f -> f1 /. f2 -> f3
```

> f[1, 2, 2, 3, 1, 3] + 2 f[1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 1]