# How to match the arguments of the function in any order

Tags: function-construction, argument-patterns

The issue is the following, with a dumb function with (4) arguments of (4) different heads (for each head is always no grater than one arguments):

```
func[x_a,y_b,z_c,w_d] := Print[x,y,z,w]
```

If I type `func[a[1],b[2],c[3],d[4]]`, it returns as its correct `a[1]b[2]c[3]d[4]`.

But if I forget the order of I should type de arguments, It doesn't works. So, I want to my function `func` still works even if I send the exchanged arguments, a permutation of them. In spite of, coding all posible order for arguments in the `func`.

Comment: Attributes[func]={Orderless}.

Comment: If only wanting to handle a subset, could ue `OrderlessPatternSequence` (in version 10.1). `func[x_a, OrderlessPatternSequence[y_b, z_c, w_d]] := Print[x, y, z, w]
func[a[1], b[2], d[3], c[4]]

a[1]b[2]c[4]d[3]`

Comment: Thanks Fred. Your comment is actually the answer.

Comment: @d555: NB - you must set the attribute *before* setting any values of Fn you want it to apply to...

Comment: I propose closing this as a duplicate of [(71463)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/71463/121) as between the question itself and my newly updated answer I believe this it well covered.

Comment: Related: [(55702)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/55702/121)