# How to canonically reorganize a list using only a limited set of manipulations?

Tags: sorting, code-request, canonicalization

I want to canonically reorganize (like `Sort`) a sequence of four objects `seq[a,b,c,d]`, *but* the only manipulations allowed are `RotateLeft` (any number of times) and `Reverse`.

The element on the left should have the lowest value.

For example, `seq[b,c,a,0]` should go to `seq[0,a,c,b]`

(below are some more examples).

$(1)\enspace\{c,b,d,a\} \longrightarrow \{a,c,b,d\}\\
(2)\enspace  \{d,a,b,a\} \longrightarrow \{a,b,a,d\}\\
(3)\enspace\{0,b,a,0\} \longrightarrow \{0,0,a,b\}$

Is there a built-in Mathematica function to do this?  How can this be done efficiently in Mathematica?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You basically want to permute the elements of the list among some specified set of permutations, and find the ordering of the list among these permutations that is canonically "first".  The set of permutations you're interested in is a subgroup of the permutation group $S_n$, generated by two generators, one of which rotates all elements one position to the left and the other of which reverses the elements.

We can use Mathematica's built-in group theory functions to do this.  `PermutationGroup` specifies a group generated by any number of permutations, and `GroupElements` tells Mathematica to explicitly calculate all the elements of this group.  We can then apply all of these permutations to the original list, apply `Sort` to that, and then take the first element of the sorted list of permuted lists.  Like so:

```
rotrevsort[listin__] := 
 Module[{list = listin, n, permlist},
  n = Length[list];
  permlist = GroupElements[PermutationGroup[{PermutationCycles[RotateLeft[Range[n]]], 
                                             PermutationCycles[Reverse[Range[n]]]}]];
  First[Sort[Permute[list, #] & /@ permlist]]
 ]

rotrevsort[{c, b, d, a}]
rotrevsort[{d, a, b, a}]
rotrevsort[{0, b, a, 0}]

(* {a, c, b, d} *)
(* {a, b, a, d} *)
(* {0, 0, a, b} *)
```

By the way, your group is only of order $2n$, i.e., there are only $2n$ possible permutations of the list that you need to sort.  (For those who know group theory, the subgroup of $S_n$ we're looking at is isomorphic to the dihedral group $D_n$.)  So if we assume that `Sort`'s algorithms don't take significantly longer to sort a list of $2n$ elements than they do a list of $n$ elements, I wouldn't expect that sorting the whole list of valid permutations would be significantly less efficient than sorting the elements of the list themselves.

Comment: I'd never heard of `PermutationCylces`, `PermutationGroup` and `GroupElements`.  Very handy functions!

Comment: @QuantumDot I [believe you have](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/58806/121) but that's OK, I forget things too. ;^)

Comment: Comparing two lists takes $O(n)$ time, though, so sorting the list of permutations should take $O(n^2\log n)$ compared to the $O(n\log n)$ time for sorting the original list.

Answer (score 3):

Just a small simplification of Michael Seifert's [excellent answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/85769/531), using the fact that you can pass a group directly to `Permute` as its second argument.

```
groupForN[n_Integer?Positive] :=
  PermutationGroup[
     {PermutationCycles@RotateLeft@#,
      PermutationCycles@Reverse@#}] &[Range@n];

smallestByRotRev[l_List] :=
  First@Sort[Permute[l, groupForN@Length@l]];
```

This gives the same answers:

```
smallestByRotRev[{c, b, d, a}]
(* {a, c, b, d} *)     

smallestByRotRev[{d, a, b, a}]
(* {a, b, a, d} *)     

smallestByRotRev[{0, b, a, 0}]
(* {0, 0, a, b} *)
```