# Set Attributes -> Orderless for only some variables in a function?

Tags: function-construction, attributes

I have the following function:

```
r12ExpUnit[n1_, n2_, n3_, n4_] := 

     r12ExpUnit[n3, n4, n1, n2] = 

       r12ExpUnit[n1, n4, n3, n2] = 

           r12ExpUnit[n3, n2, n1, n4] = ((some function))
```

Here n1, n2, n3, n4 are indices in which n1 and n3 are interchangeable, and n2 and n4 are interchangeable.  Is there a way to use `SetAttributes` to declare these two pairs of indices are orderless without declaring all four orderless?

Comment: I believe this question is a duplicate of [(55702)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/55702/121)

Answer (score 5):

`Orderless` sorts your argument in canonical order and you might want to explore the possibility to use a helper function to sort only some.

```
With[{f = Function[, ##, {Orderless}]},
 r12ExpUnit[n1_, n2_, n3_, n4_] := 
  somefunc[#1, #3, #2, #4] &[f[n1, n3], f[n2, n4]]
]
```

Here, you use `f` to specifically sort the argument pairs `{n1,n3}` and `{n2,n4}`. I don't find this particularly beautiful and I'm not sure that you can come up with a better overall design, but the information you have given only permit vague guesses.

Anyway, as you can easily see, `somefunc` will always be called with your specific pairs in canonical order without ordering all arguments:

```
r12ExpUnit[n2, n1, n4, n2]
r12ExpUnit[n4, n2, n2, n1]
r12ExpUnit[n2, n2, n4, n1]
r12ExpUnit[n4, n1, n2, n2]

(* somefunc[n2, n1, n4, n2] *)
(* somefunc[n2, n1, n4, n2] *)
(* somefunc[n2, n1, n4, n2] *)
(* somefunc[n2, n1, n4, n2] *)
```

Answer (score 3):

Another possibility is to use `OrderedQ[]` to check if the corresponding arguments are in canonical order, and then use `Sort[]` for canonicalization:

```
r12ExpUnit[n1_, n2_, n3_, n4_] /; ! (OrderedQ[{n1, n3}] && OrderedQ[{n2, n4}]) := 
      r12ExpUnit @@ (Join[Sort[{n1, n3}], Sort[{n2, n4}]][[{1, 3, 2, 4}]])
```

Test:

```
r12ExpUnit[n1, n2, n3, n4] === r12ExpUnit[n3, n4, n1, n2] ===
r12ExpUnit[n1, n4, n3, n2] === r12ExpUnit[n3, n2, n1, n4]
   True

(* halirutan's example *)
r12ExpUnit[n2, n1, n4, n2] === r12ExpUnit[n4, n2, n2, n1] === 
r12ExpUnit[n2, n2, n4, n1] === r12ExpUnit[n4, n1, n2, n2]
   True
```

Comment: I think this question is a duplicate of [(55702)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/55702/121); would you look and tell me if you agree?

Comment: Yup, lemme do a few clicks...

Comment: You might consider reposting your method the original thread.

Comment: I dunno, evanb's solution there is halfway through that of mine, but less bulletproof. (And jose's solution is vastly more elegant.)

Comment: Perhaps be a benefactor and enhance his answer then?

Comment: I left a comment already. :)