# Match items in list, forward and reverse order without sorting list or defining list as Orderless

Tags: pattern-matching

I'm using the following code to pick out (match) two specified items in a list (specified as `anum_` and `bnum_`), change them both and then return an output list. The output list has the two specified items changed but the rest left intact:

```
qubits = {qubit[1, "x", "y", "z"], qubit[2, "x", "y", "z"], qubit[3, "x", "y", "z"]};

processQubits[anum_, bnum_, {before___, qubit[anum_, s1_, s2_, s3_], middle___, qubit[bnum_, t1_, t2_, t3_], after___}] := {before, qubit[anum, s1<>t1, s2<>t2, s3<>t3], middle, qubit[bnum, s1<>t1, s2<>t2, s3<>t3], after}

(*Matches and returns "xx", "yy", "zz" etc.*)
processQubits[1, 2, qubits]
(*Does not match due to ordering*)
processQubits[2, 1, qubits]

Out[4]= {qubit[1,xx,yy,zz],qubit[2,xx,yy,zz],qubit[3,x,y,z]}

Out[6]= processQubits[2,1,{qubit[1,x,y,z],qubit[2,x,y,z],qubit[3,x,y,z]}]
```

Unsurprisingly, the match succeeds when I list the items in the order in which they appear in the list (e.g. `processQubits[1, 2, ..]`, but not when I list them in reverse order (e.g. `processQubits[2, 1, ...]`).

Is there a well-used idiom to match these two items and return an output list regardless of which order the items are specified in?

Comment: Related: [(55702)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/55702/121)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Does adding an ancillary definition for `processQubits` such as:

```
processQubits[anum_, bnum_, rest__] := 
 processQubits[bnum, anum, rest] /; ! OrderedQ[{anum, bnum}]
```

do what you want, i.e. both calls above return the same thing?

This extra definition ensures that `anum` and `bnum` always appear in the argument list of `processQubits` in "canonical" order. In effect it is applying the `Orderless` attribute to only the first two arguments.

Comment: Thanks. I assume that your solution uses the fact that a list of arguments in Mathematica is considered as a standard list and the !OrderedQ lets the engine know that they can appear in any order? Would be great if you could add a little more info about how the solution works; it's quite a step for folks like me who are a little more used to procedural programming languages!

Comment: A slightly cleaner form, IMHO: `/; Order[anum, bnum] < 0`( @DavidB )

Answer (score 0):

In versions 10.1+ there is [OrderlessPatternSequence](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/OrderlessPatternSequence.html)

```
ClearAll[pQubits]
pQubits[OrderlessPatternSequence[anum_, bnum_], {before___, qubit[anum_, s1_, s2_, s3_],
   middle___, qubit[bnum_, t1_, t2_, t3_], after___}] := 
 {before, qubit[anum, s1 <> t1, s2 <> t2, s3 <> t3], middle, 
  qubit[bnum, s1 <> t1, s2 <> t2, s3 <> t3], after}
```

Examples:

```
pQubits[1, 2, qubits]
```

> {qubit[1,"xx","yy","zz"], qubit[2,"xx","yy","zz"], qubit[3,"x","y","z"]}

```
pQubits[2, 1, qubits]
```

> {qubit[1,"xx","yy","zz"], qubit[2,"xx","yy","zz"], qubit[3,"x","y","z"]}

```
pQubits[3, 2, RotateRight@ qubits]
```

> {qubit[3,"xx","yy","zz"], qubit[1,"x","y","z"], qubit[2,"xx","yy","zz"]}

```
pQubits[2, 3, qubits]
```

> {qubit[1,"x","y","z"], qubit[2,"xx","yy","zz"], qubit[3,"xx","yy","zz"]}